# PHP Guzzle Get Request Format

Tags: json, guzzle

I'm trying to get a JSON feed with Guzzle and this is my first time.

The body sample I was given is:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "key": "samplekeyhere",
        "secret": "samplesecrethere"
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    $res = $client->request(
                'GET',
                'https://urltofeed',
                [
                    "verify" => false, // JUST FOR TESTING NOW
                    "headers" => [
                        "Content-Type" => "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                    ],
                    "json" => [
                        "key" => "samplekeyhere",
                        "secret" => "samplesecrethere"
                    ]
                ]
    );
    $body = $res->getBody();

$jsonResponse = json_decode($body);
var_dump($jsonResponse);
```

The output is:

```
status code is200object(stdClass)#2455 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["msg"]=> string(7) "Error 1" }
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax here or should I be asking for a new key and secret?

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonResponse = json_decode($body->getContents());
```

Because the body is an instance of `StreamInterface`, not a simple string.